# MySQL query timing out only with specific column selected and WHERE JSON_CONTAINS()

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-workbench, mariadb-10.2

Consider the following queries:

```
SELECT uID, name FROM table WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(email, '{"key": "email@email.com"}', '$');
SELECT uID, name, history FROM table WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(email, '{"key": "email@email.com"}', '$');
SELECT uID, name, history FROM table WHERE uID = 1;
```

`uID`, `name`, and `history` columns are INT(10), JSON, and JSON datatypes, respectively. `email` column is also JSON datatype.

Queries 1 and 3 both complete in a moment. Query 2 times out after 30 seconds (**Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query**).

My question is this: Why is it that combining a `SELECT history` and `WHERE JSON_CONTAINS` causes a timeout, whereas having either or in the query is fine?

Comment: Do you have a lot of rows? This could be a painful table scan. Check with `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to see how long it's taking.

Comment: genrated an index on $.key  see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html

Comment: @tadman There's over 60k rows, however I'm not sure why that would affect this particular case, since query #1 works perfectly fine.

Comment: Time for `EXPLAIN` to help, presumably.

Comment: @tadman Using `EXPLAIN` doesn't reveal much, if anything. Including `SHOW WARNINGS` gives me a `Code 1003`, which according to mariadb documentation just means `YES` which is obviously not very helpful. As far as I can tell from using `EXPLAIN` there's nothing wrong with these queries.